# datetime format conversion invalid string

Tags: vb.net, datetime, type-conversion

I have asked this question before and used the soln but for some reason it just does not work this time around. Hopefully someone else can see the error/missing element. Iparse a date that is in string format and would like to convert it to a datetime format but cannot figure out how to do this. The date appears as such:

```
Tue May 08 20:38:42 +08:00 2012
```

here is my conversion code:

```
Dim postDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(contentDate, "ddd MMMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
contentDate = postDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

The error is on the first line : "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime "

Comment: this function is  in a windows application. The source of the date come from json api results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I believe the issue is that the date you have as your sample was not a Thursday, but a Sunday.  In addition, I think you need to use capital letters for the Hour since it looks like you are getting military time.

```
Dim postDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(contentDate, "ddd MMMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Once I made these changes, it worked.

Comment: thanks for your response but I changed it to Tue May 08 20:38:42 +08:00 2012 which is the correct date. I was trying different combinations cause I thought it was the date.

Comment: Ok bless you. I just saw that I had lower caps for the hour: hh instead of HH and that worked now.